# Storing objects for a struct

Tags: ios, object, struct

Just curious, how do I store this struct into a property

```
void CGContextAddCurveToPoint (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGFloat cp1x,
   CGFloat cp1y,
   CGFloat cp2x,
   CGFloat cp2y,
   CGFloat x,
   CGFloat y
);
```

like

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) void ??
```

Comment: what struct? isn't this a function prototype? for normal struct such as CGRect, `@property (strong, nonatomic) CGRect rect;`

Comment: It keep saying Unknown type for name CGContextAddCurveToPoint

Comment: @xlc0212, you can't declare **strong** property for CGRect

Comment: i use assign btw: @property(assign, nonatomic)        CGContextAddCurveToPoint  curveObject;

Comment: what u are showing here is not a struct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are presenting in your question is not a `struct` it is a `method`.

It is possible to do the following though. Declare a struct first:

```
typedef struct 
{
   CGContextRef c;
   CGFloat cp1x;
   CGFloat cp1y;
   CGFloat cp2x;
   CGFloat cp2y;
   CGFloat x;
   CGFloat y;
} yourStruct;
```

and secondly declare a property that will have a type specification of `yourStruct`

e.g: `@property yourStruct yourPropertyName;`

Comment: I believe you need to `typedef yourStruct yourStruct;` to use it as in the example.

Comment: Aha, i noticed it in the header file. Instead of defining at as a struct, i define it as a NSObject. Thanks!

Comment: you could also declare @property struct yourStruct yourPropertyName; if you didn't typedef your struct like i did previously